# transforming a nested json object

Tags: json, object, merge, jq

I have a nested json object like so:

```
{
  "results": {
    "category_a": {
      "types": {
        "type_a": {},
        "type_b": {},
        "type_c": {}
      }
    },
    "category_b": {
      "types": {
        "type_y": {},
        "type_z": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I'd like to squash it down it into a simpler nested object:

```
{
  "category_a": [
    "type_a",
    "type_b",
    "type_c"
  ],
  "category_b": [
    "type_y",
    "type_z"
  ]
}
```

This is what I have so far, which is close to what I want:

```
.results
| to_entries[]
| {
    (.key): [
      .value.types | keys[]
    ]
  }
```

except that the output is line-oriented instead of being a single object:

```
{
  "category_a": [
    "type_a",
    "type_b",
    "type_c"
  ]
}
{
  "category_b": [
    "type_y",
    "type_z"
  ]
}
```

How can I combine those two json objects into one? Do I need to approach the transformation differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with your program as a starting point, you can simply wrap the separate objects in square brackets, and then use `add`:

```
.results
| [to_entries[] | { (.key): [ .value.types | keys[] ] } ]
| add
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work, although `add` isn't the most intuitive name for what that function does to that type of data structure.